# pd.Series replace first occurrence

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

When trying to replace the min of the series with np.NaN I am getting a "multiple" replacement.

I have tried to use the series.replace method but it results in the replacement of all the occurrences at the min.

As an example:

```
series = pd.Series([0,0,1,1])

#when calling the replace:
series = series.apply(lambda x: x.replace(min(x),np.NaN))

#the output is:
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   1
3   1

#and the desired output is:
0   NaN
1   0
2   1
3   1
```

So essentially, how can I replace only the first occurrence of the repeated minimum?

Comment: As you wrote under that you need to replace multiple rows, and not just one as stated in the original question, take a look at df.drop_duplicates().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `loc`+`idxmin`

`idxmin` returns the index of the first occurrence of the minimum value of the series.

```
sss.loc[sss.idxmin()] = np.nan
```

Comment: Is there a way to run this inside of the apply and lambda since I need to apply this to multiple rows?

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple rows"? The question makes it sound like the whole point is to ensure that only one row is affected. Please ask a new question and give a *complete* example that demonstrates the desired output for a given input, and shows everything that needs to happen.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel just realized I messed this up lol, meant to say columns. Thanks for your HELPFUL comment

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.where` and add a second condition to have the first duplicate value return True with `duplcated`.

```
s = pd.Series([0,0,1,1,4])

s = np.where(s.duplicated(keep='last') & s.eq(s.min()), np.nan, s)

s

Out[1]: array([nan,  0.,  1.,  1., 4.])
```

This method will not replace your min if it's not duplicated unlike using `idxmin`.

```
s = pd.Series([0,1,1,3,4,4])

s = np.where(s.duplicated(keep='last') & s.eq(s.min()), np.nan, s)

s

Out[1]: array([0., 1., 1., 3., 4., 4.])
```